# Loading csv with mal-formed last line in Postgres, PL/pgSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I am loading list of csv files using a cursor in PL/pgsql and the problem is that some of the csv files have a string as the last row instead of proper data. When I try to load these files this obviously leads to an error. I would prefer not to have to do a pre-processing step where I fix the csv's and would rather do it on the fly.

How can I avoid this problem?

```
FOR file_record IN
   SELECT file_path
   FROM source_files
LOOP
   DROP TABLE mytemp;
   CREATE TABLE mytemp
   (
       dataA numeric,
       dataB numeric
   );
   FORMAT('COPY mytemp
        FROM %L
        DELIMITER '',''
        CSV HEADER;', file_record.file_path);
END LOOP;
```

Comment: `COPY` does not provide any way to handle such a situation.